# Want to run console.log once

Tags: javascript

I have a function here and my question is: How can i run the console.log once and the function that im calling keeps on running?

```
function zetTemperatuur() {

    var handmatigeTemp = document.getElementById("gewenstetemperatuur").value;

    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (handmatigeTemp < temperatuur) {
            console.log("De motor van de wijnkoeler begint te draaien en zal geleidelijk aan dalen naar de gewenste temperatuur.");

            trekAf();
        } else if (handmatigeTemp == temperatuur) {
            console.log("Uw Wijnkoeler is op de juiste temperatuur, namelijk " + temperatuur + ". De motor zal nu uitschakelen om energie te besparen.");
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        } else {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: `trekAf` certainly is not the correct way to name that function :P

Comment: Problem of `trekAf` is that it's too generic.

Comment: And certainly not when `trekAf` is beforer `handmatig` :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use just a flag:

```
function zetTemperatuur() {

                var handmatigeTemp = document.getElementById("gewenstetemperatuur").value;
                var flag = false;

                var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (handmatigeTemp < temperatuur) {
                        if (flag == false) {
                          flag = true;
                          console.log("De motor van de wijnkoeler begint te draaien en zal geleidelijk aan dalen naar de gewenste temperatuur.");
                        }

                        trekAf();
                    }
                    else if (handmatigeTemp == temperatuur) {
                        console.log("Uw Wijnkoeler is op de juiste temperatuur, namelijk " + temperatuur + ". De motor zal nu uitschakelen om energie te besparen.");
                        clearInterval(myInterval);
                    }

                    else {
                        clearInterval(myInterval);
                    }
                      }, 3000);
            }
```

**EDIT**

Shorter version:

```
function zetTemperatuur() {

                var handmatigeTemp = document.getElementById("gewenstetemperatuur").value;
                var flag = false;

                var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (handmatigeTemp < temperatuur) {
                        (!flag) && (flag = true);
                        console.log("De motor van de wijnkoeler begint te draaien en zal geleidelijk aan dalen naar de gewenste temperatuur.");

                        trekAf();
                    }
                    else if (handmatigeTemp == temperatuur) {
                        console.log("Uw Wijnkoeler is op de juiste temperatuur, namelijk " + temperatuur + ". De motor zal nu uitschakelen om energie te besparen.");
                        clearInterval(myInterval);
                    }

                    else {
                        clearInterval(myInterval);
                    }
                      }, 3000);
            }
```

Comment: Just added a shorter version :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe your shorter version will not work as the OP requests.  Sure, it will flip the flag properly, but the log will happen no matter what since it isn't conditionally called based on said flag.

Comment: I fixed it, but edit needs to be accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe be use a flag like :

```
 var logged = false;

 /*In your function*/
 if(!logged)
 {
  console.log(something);
  logged = true;
 }
```

Comment: this one I used :D

Answer (score 5):

Use Lodash's [_.once](https://lodash.com/docs#once)

```
function log() {
  console.log('message')
}
var _log = _.once(log);
_log();
_log();
```

'message' will be logged once.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (!window.opener++) {
    console.log("print's once")
  }
  else {
    console.log("print's the remaining times")
  }
}, 3000);
```

`opener` is a flag added to the globally available Window object, and `window.opener++` is an increment operator (used postfix). It increments window.opener and returns the value **before** incrementing. So on the first loop, `if (!window.opener++)` evaluates to `if (!null)` (null is a falsey value, so this is true), and on the second iteration `if (!1)`. The increment operator can also be used prefix to return the value **after** incrementing.

https://jsfiddle.net/64atz4kq/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

Comment: I have no idea why this received a downvote. It's a concise solution that work's exactly as the OP requested.

Comment: I agree! I tried the fiddle and its shows us the difference, so I voted up.

Comment: How does this work though? What does `window.opener++` do?

Comment: The link is dead by the way.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the link, and added a description to the answer (should have done it the first time).

Answer (score 0):

Solution for multiple console.logs

```
var flag = array();
var logger = function(id, message) {
    if(!flag[id]) {
        console.log(message);
        flag[id] = true;
    }
}
var yourFunction = function(something) {
    // your code here
    if(something) {
        logger(1, "german german deutch");
    }
    else {
        logger(2, "another german");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a function for this.

```
console.logOnce = function(msg) {
  window.__loggedFunctions = window.__loggedFunctions || [];
  var caller = arguments.callee.caller.toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < __loggedFunctions.length; i++ ) {
    if (caller == __loggedFunctions[i]) return;
  }
  window.logOnce = arguments;

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);  
  }

  __loggedFunctions.push(caller);
}
```